# Hints for proof that Variety $X$ of (dimension $0$) is discrete.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

I have come across a statement in a textbook which has been left as an exercises for the reader, and as such there is no proof.

I am looking for some HINTS to get me started on a proof, as I am do not think I am fully understanding the "of dimension zero" aspect of the statement.

> If we have a variety $X$, where $\dim(X) = 0$, then $X$ is discrete.

I think I should reduce it to the affine case, but I am not sure where to go from there ...?

Note we are assuming all varieties are finite type over the field K, where K is an algebraically closed field, thus Noetherian.

Comment: What is your definition of a variety? Are they necessarily noetherian, for example by being of finite type over a field?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, we are assuming all varieties are finite type over the field K, where K is an algebraically closed field, thus Noetherian.

Comment: Is this an exercise in some class you're all taking? This is like the fourth time this question's been asked in the last day.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the result is true for any noetherian zero-dimensional scheme. All other properties of a variety are not needed.

It is easy to reduce to the affine case: If a topological space is covered by discrete open sets, it is itself discrete. This a very easy exercise in point set topology.

For the affine case, let $M_1, \dotsc, M_n$ be the finitely many prime (=maximal) ideals of a zero-dimensional noetherian ring $A$. Note that there are finitely many, because the ring is noetherian. For any given subset of those prime ideals (i.e. any subset of $\operatorname{Spec} A$), let $I$ be their product. Then $V(I)$ equals the given subset, i.e. it is closed.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks for your input, but I still cant see why the fact that $V(I)$ is closed implies that the variety is discrete?

Comment: I showed that any subset is closed. This is the same as showing that any subset is open.